# AudioContext doesn't have some methods

Tags: node.js, web-audio-api

I'm trying to run this [node wrapper for pink trombone,](https://github.com/giuliomoro/pink-trombone/tree/e7161e35b1e9988c9e05f0d5ea58691ad8cfe8c8) which uses an AudioContext to play audio in a fake browser. When I try to run the program with `node nodeWrapper.js`, I get the following error:

```
evalmachine.<anonymous>:476
    var aspirateFilter = this.audioContext.createBiquadFilter();
                                           ^
TypeError: this.audioContext.createBiquadFilter is not a function
    at Object.startSound (evalmachine.<anonymous>:476:48)
    at Object.startMouse (evalmachine.<anonymous>:344:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jessy/giuliomoro-pink-trombone/pink-trombone/nodeWrapper.js:10:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
```

`this.audioContext` looks like a normal AudioContext object, with properties sampleRate, numberOfChannels, outStream, etc -- but it's missing methods like `createBiquadFilter`. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Let's follow the dependencies and see where we end up...

The node wrapper for pink trombone depends on ["web-audio-api": "^0.2.2"](https://github.com/giuliomoro/pink-trombone/blob/bela/package.json#L8)

The [web-audio-api package on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-audio-api) refers to [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/audiojs/web-audio-api).

The readme says:

> What's Implemented
>
> AudioContext (partially)
>   AudioParam (almost there)
>   AudioBufferSourceNode
>   ScriptProcessorNode
>   GainNode
>   OscillatorNode (coming soon)
>   DelayNode (coming soon)

Which is missing BiquadFilter. And just to make sure, have a look in the [lib folder](https://github.com/audiojs/web-audio-api/tree/master/lib), there is no BiquadFilter there.